# Need help to optimize my stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I need help optimizing my stored procedure. This is for our fact table, and currently the stored procedure truncates the table, and then loads the data back in. I want to get rid of truncating and instead append new rows or delete rows by a last_update column which currently does not exist. There also is a last_update table with one column, which changes at every stored procedure run, but I'd rather the `last_update` be a column in the table itself, rather than a separate column.

I've created a trigger that should update the last_updated column with the current date when the stored procedure runs, but I would also like to get rid of truncating and instead append/delete rows as well. The way the stored procedure is currently structured is making it difficult for me to figure out how best to do it.

The stored procedure begins by adding data into 2 temp tables, then adds the data from the two temp tables into a 3rd temp table, then truncates the current FACT TABLE and then the 3rd temp table finally inserts into the FACT table.

```
--CLEAR LAST UPDATE TABLE
TRUNCATE TABLE ADM.LastUpdate;

--SET NEW LAST UPDATE TIME
INSERT INTO ADM.LastUpdate(TABLE_NAME, UPDATE_TIME)
VALUES('FactBP', CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 100)+' (CST)');

--CHECK TO SEE IF TEMP TABLES EXISTS THEN DROP
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TEMP_CARTON', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_CARTON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TEMP_ORDER', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP_ORDER;

--CREATE TEMP TABLES
SELECT *
INTO #TEMP_CARTON
FROM [dbo].[FACT_CARTON_V];

SELECT *
INTO #TEMP_ORDER
FROM [dbo].[FACT_ORDER_V];

--CHECK TO SEE IF DATA EXISTS IN #TEMP_CARTON AND #TEMP_ORDER
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_CARTON)
    AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TEMP_ORDER)

--CODE HERE joins the data from #TEMP_CARTON and #TEMP ORDER and puts it into a 3rd temp table #TEMP_FACT.


--CLEAR ALL DATA FROM FACTBP
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.FactBP;

--INSERT DATA FROM TEMP TABLE TO FACTBP
INSERT INTO dbo.FactBP
SELECT 
[SOURCE]
      ,[DC_ORDER_NUMBER]
      ,[CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID]
      ,[BILL_TO]
      ,[CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE]
      ,[SHIP_TO]
      ,[CUSTOMER_NAME]
      ,[SALES_ORDER]
      ,[ORDER_CARRIER]
      ,[CARRIER_SERVICE_ID]
      ,[CREATE_DATE]
      ,[CREATE_TIME]
      ,[ALLOCATION_DATE]
      ,[REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE]
      ,[ADJ_REQ_SHIP]
      ,[CANCEL_DATE]
      ,[DISPATCH_DATE]
      ,[RELEASED_DATE]
      ,[RELEASED_TIME]
      ,[PRIORITY_ORDER]
      ,[SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER]
      ,[ORDER_HDR_STATUS]
      ,[ORDER_STATUS]
      ,[DELIVERY_NUMBER]
      ,[DCMS_ORDER_TYPE]
      ,[ORDER_TYPE]
      ,[MATERIAL]
      ,[QUALITY]
      ,[MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1]
      ,[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1]
      ,[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2]
      ,[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3]
      ,[DIVISION]
      ,[DIVISION_DESC]
      ,[ORDER_QTY]
      ,[ORDER_SELECTED_QTY]
      ,[CARTON_PARCEL_ID]
      ,[CARTON_ID]
      ,[SHIP_DATE]
      ,[SHIP_TIME]
      ,[PACKED_DATE]
      ,[PACKED_TIME]
      ,[ADJ_PACKED_DATE]
      ,[FULL_CASE_PULL_STATUS]
      ,[CARRIER_ID]
      ,[TRAILER_ID]
      ,[WAVE_NUMBER]
      ,[DISPATCH_RELEASE_PRIORITY]
      ,[CARTON_TOTE_COUNT]
      ,[PICK_PACK_METHOD]
      ,[RELEASED_QTY]
      ,[SHIP_QTY]
      ,[MERCHANDISE_STYLE]
      ,[PICK_WAREHOUSE]
      ,[PICK_AREA]
      ,[PICK_ZONE]
      ,[PICK_AISLE]
      ,EST_DEL_DATE
FROM #TEMP_FACT;
```

Currently, since I've added the last_updated column into my FACT TABLE and created a trigger, I don't actually pass any value via the stored procedure for it, so I get an error

> An object or column name is missing or empty.

I am not sure as to where I'm supposed to pass any value for the `LAST_UPDATED` column.

Here is the trigger I've created for updating the `last_updated` column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER last_updated
ON dbo.factbp
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
    UPDATE dbo.factbp
    SET last_updated = GETDATE()
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE dbo.factbp.id = i.id
```

Comment: for testing purposes you can use getdate(). But may want to revisit that logic based on business needs.

Comment: Kindly put your `trigger` code. Let me know how you will identify `record wise last updated` or not for `insert/update/delete` in FACT TABLE.

Comment: or you can also hardcode a future date; again based on some business logic eg '9999-09-09'; but can also be used for ISNULL in case no matching criteria is found for Last_Update_Date column. Again business rule.

Comment: @JIKEN I have added the trigger code above. the SP runs once a day, so I would like for any rows that are older than 2 months to be removed, and any new rows that currently do not exist in the table to be appended.

Comment: @UmairAhmed - You need to change your trigger code from `AFTER UPDATE` to `AFTER INSERT`.

Comment: I changed the trigger to AFTER INSERT, but I still get the same error. Is it because the "LAST_UPDATED" column only exists in the FACT TABLE, but not in the tables from where the data is inserted into the FACT TABLE? I know im not passing a value but that's because im anticipating the trigger to work upon the SP run.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to create primary keys on the two temp tables  #TEMP_CARTON and        #TEMP_ORDER and use the intersect command to get the rows that are common to both tables:

```
select * from  #TEMP_CARTON
intersect
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_ORDER
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer. I just had to put "null" for the last_updated value during Insert, and then the Trigger took care of adding the timestamp on its own.